# Creating a custom "flat" projection definition in proj4

Tags: python, coordinate-system, proj

I want to create a simple, custom projection in proj4. I need it to be completly flat ( rectangular coordinates ). Starts in point (0,0), meters as unit, everything else - as simple as possible. What parameters my definition should have to achieve it?

Am I even able to do it? Ignoring the curvature of the Earth?

Comment: It might help if you can explain what you are really trying to achieve ("why"). In general, we use proj to transform and project points. What would a meaningful conversion look like in your case? I'd guess you are just looking for a false easting and false northing of 0,0.

Comment: I need a projection for fictional, flat world (not real one), but I still want to be able to use all GIS tools, so I want a proper coordinate system somehow defined

Comment: So you don't really want to project it, you just want a coordinate system (EPSG number or similar) works in your tools? If so, its sometimes called an engineering coordinate system - https://epsg.io/5806 is an example, https://epsg.io/5807 is in metres if that helps.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, as I'm not very experienced in that matter. Is there any place where I can read more about engineering coordinate systems in general?

Comment: @Mativane did you resolve this? I would also need a "flat earth" projection for my fantasy mapping needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use custom **EPSG** code (starting from 10000 number) and this definition (with a=0 and b=0):

`+proj=merc +a=0 +b=0 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs`