# Generating a custom flat projection in pyproj

Tags: python, coordinate-system, proj, pyproj

I have little experience with pyproj, but I want to achieve the following task:
I have a trajectory of a robot, given in lat/long coordinates which I want to convert to x/y Coordinates. And I want to do this using a "flat" cartesian coordinate system originating at a lat/long combination of my choice. I realize that this projection only works for a small area, but that is okay with me, as the area I am looking at is small (<10km in all directions.)
Here is what I achieved so far, which is a transverse mercator projection (or so I was told).
[image: Robot path in projection]

I have used the following code.

```py
import pyproj as proj

crs_wgs = proj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')  # assuming you're using WGS84 geographic
    crs_bng = proj.Proj(init='epsg:27700')  # use a locally appropriate projected CRS
    # then cast your geographic coordinate pair to the projected system
    x, y = proj.transform(crs_wgs, crs_bng, s['gps_lng'], s['gps_lat'])
```

So this question is two-fold:

1. Which Projection do I use to achieve a local flat cartesian coordinate system
2. Howto define this projection at my given lat/long combination

I was told to ask this question in a new thread, [see my old question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330445/generating-custom-projection-in-pyproj). Also [a similar question has been asked](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316556/creating-a-custom-flat-projection-definition-in-proj4), but it seemed to be too unspecific to be answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an Azimuthal Equidistant projection centred on your origin point.

In PROJ4 syntax, "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=1.234 +lon_0=5.678".

That long/lat coordinate should project to (0,0) in that coordinate system, and points away from there should be in metres. You might want to add "+datum=WGS84 +units=m" but they may be default. Not sure what ellipsoid is default so maybe add an "+ellps=GRS80" or similar...

Note you can construct a projection string using this argument-based form:

```
>>> pargs = proj.Proj(proj="aeqd", lat_0=gps_lat, lon_0=gps_long, datum="WGS84", units="m")
```

which means you don't have to make sure your arguments line up with the `{0}` etc format replacement markers if you try doing it with `format`.

Answer (score 2):

So @Spacedman pointed me in the right direction, all praise goes to him. I just want to show the complete code for my question:

```py
import pyproj as proj
...
crs_wgs = proj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')  # assuming you're using WGS84 geographic

#Erect own local flat cartesian coordinate system
cust = proj.Proj("+proj=aeqd +lat_0={0} +lon_0={1} +datum=WGS84 +units=m".format(gps_lat_0, gps_long_0))
x, y = proj.transform(crs_wgs, cust, gps_long, gps_lat)
```

with `gps_lat_0/gps_long_0` being the inital coordinates, and `gps_lat/gps_long` being the list of gps coordinates you want to transfer

Comment: I've added a note on how to use the argument-based method of making projections which I think is neater since the argument name and its value are closer.