# Abnormal results projecting WGS84 to local Azimuthal Equidistant projection with pyproj

Tags: python, coordinate-system, pyproj, azimuth

I am trying to project regular WGS84 coordinates to a local projected system (Azimuthal Equidistant), using meters and centered on the eiffel tower (as an exemple). I am using python 3.8.2 and pyproj 2.4.1 for that.

I tried to reproduce the method of Spacedman from [[this post]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/330750/112815), but the results I get are clearly wrong ...

Here is my test code, trying to get the coordinates of Le Louvre Museum in that system :

```
# coding: utf8
import pyproj

def to_local(lon_angle, lat_angle, origin):
  crs_wgs84 = pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326') # WGS84 input projection (angle)
  crs_aeqd = pyproj.Proj(proj='aeqd', datum='WGS84', lon_0=origin[0], lat_0=origin[1], units='m') # Local Azimuthal Equidistant projection, centered on the 'origin' parameter
  x, y = pyproj.transform(crs_wgs84, crs_aeqd, lon_angle, lat_angle)
  return(x, y)

origin = (2.294473, 48.858440) # Eiffel tower in Paris
destination = (2.335769, 48.861062) # Le Louvre Museum

x, y = to_local(destination[0], destination[1], origin)
print(f'In local system centred on origin, destination has coordinates ({x}, {y})') # Result, in meters, should be around (3030, 290)
```

From what I roughly computed manually, I should get something like `3030 meters` as longitude and `290 meters` as latitude, both positive since Le Louvre is North-West from the Eiffel Tower, but here is the output :

```
> In local system centred on origin, destination has coordinates (5635219.051216577, -3788748.14149113)
```

I don't understand thoses values, what am I missing here ?

Comment: is your WGS84 lat/lon not lon/lat maybe?

Comment: I tried your conversion with cs2cs, and I got `3030.09809, 292.40716` , but when I reverse the lon/lat of the destination, I get the same result as you do which is `5635219.05122, -3788748.14149`. Looks like some kind of reversal of lat/lon occurs somewhere indeed...

Comment: please answer your question with an answer not by editing your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a link to a related pyproj issue: https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/538

Here is a link to more information about the axis order changes: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6

In summary, you need to either be aware of your axis order on input/output or use the always_xy=True when creating the pyproj.Transformer.